# How to access value from resource bundle using on the fly (dynamic) generated key

Tags: jsf-2

i declared a variable named **item**

and create a **bundle**. it contain some data as follow

```
StudentAdd=student/Create.xhtml
StudentEdit=student/Edit.xhtml
StudentList=student/List.xhtml
DepartmentAdd=department/Create.xhtml
```

i want to include different xhtml page by the change of variable data

here is my xhtml code

```
<c:forEach items="#{ajaxBean.chcekItem}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
                    <p:tab id="#{item}" title="#{item}" closable="true">                            
                        <ui:include src="#{bundle.#{item}}"/>   

                    </p:tab>
                </c:forEach>
```

i can try above way but show following error message ...

```
/index.xhtml @57,66 src="#{bundle.#{item}}" The identifier [#] is not a valid Java identifier as required by section 1.19 of the EL specification (Identifier ::= Java language identifier). This check can be disabled by setting the system property org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK to true.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `<ui:include src="#{bundle.#{item}}"/>`

use `<ui:include src="#{bundle[item]}"/>`

Comment: You are welcome , also take a look at this: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-and-resource-bundles-example/